# Real analysis book reference

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

What are the best books to self study real analysis? I am a physics masters student and am looking forward to study representation theory. I want to study the real analysis I need for studying functional analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For self-study, I strongly recommend Abbott's "Understanding Analysis".  He does an excellent job of motivating the abstract concepts and introducing the frequently unintuitive behavior of infinite sets and processes.

Comment: Any recommendations for functional analysis?

Comment: functional analysis (and other modern math topics) --- [**Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471504599) by Erwin Kreyszig (1978) *AND* [**Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1575242389) by George F. Simmons (1963) *AND* the books [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718334/13130) *AND* Paul Roman's 2-volume work **Some Modern Mathematics for Physicists and Other Outsiders** [Volume 1 contents](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780080180977/some-modern-mathematics-for-physicists-and-other-outsiders).

Comment: We used Folland's "Real Analysis" in my graduate RA class, but I found that I wanted more of a Topology/Measure Theory background to really understand it.  You might find some useful comments at this discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025828/should-i-learn-measure-theory-before-learning-probability/3025932#3025932